# How to display date and time in Excel in local timezone

Tags: excel, datetime, timezone

I have several workbooks of which me and colleagues refresh data. To indicate to our users the date time of the refresh, this is put in a field in the sheet. Our team is located all over the world, in different time zones.
If my Shanghai colleague refreshes it, and he puts in 11 a.m. Oct 5th, then a user opening the file in Amsterdam on 9 a.m. Oct 5th, will sees that is has been refreshed 2 hrs in the future, as that person is unaware that this is CST and not CET.

Is there a way to enter a date time, that shows up in the time of the local timezone? So the user in Amsterdam will (in the above example) see that it is refreshed Oct 5th 5 a.m. and the user in Boston sees Oct 4th 23 p.m.? Adding the timezone as indicator is no good as I want to assume that the user is plain stupid and doesn't know what is CET, CST, EDT etc without googling.

Thanks,
Carl

Comment: From a naive programmer's perspective: If you enter the date/time manually, you could agree to use UTC, no?

Comment: Easiest way would be, indeed, manually entered data in same UTC. Developing a code to get that, depending who/where is opening the file, to convert the datetime, is really complex and not sure if worth it.

Comment: I'm wondering if the file properties of a shared file like this would show the proper modification date/time. If so, I'd go with an UDF like [this](https://www.rowshare.com/blog/tips/displaying-last-modification-time-in-excel/)

Comment: VBA does not provide any facilities for dealing with UTC (or DST) times. You'll need to get that information using Windows API functions. See the late Chip Pearson's page on [Time Zones and Daylight Savings Time](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/TimeZoneAndDaylightTime.aspx) for some examples